# How to install specific(older) version of sqlite

Tags: 18.04, sqlite

I want to install a previous version of SQLite(<=3.26.0).
And so far I am not able to find a way to do so in ubuntu.
As my current version is causing me bugs with a Django project.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fiddling around with package versions, I would recommend using `pip` (and `virtualenv`) instead, then you can install whatever version you need for your application, without changing the whole system.